# There are no messages in Monitor/Debug Logs after call of System.debug

Tags: debugging

There are no messages in `Monitor/Debug Logs` after call of `System.debug`. However I can see them in Developer Console.

```
System.debug(Logginglevel.INFO,'MsgTxt');
System.debug(Logginglevel.DEBUG,'MsgTxt');
```

Is there any settings or some setup routine in **Developer Edition** to make them appear?

Comment: if you call anonymus apex, there should be a entry in the debug log list in case if you setup that for your user and time. Ensure that its correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Debug Log, Please select Level and Date of Now and next day(for making sure click the link beside the date). That could be the reason why you are not seeing in Debug Log.